# Why cant I add same element to the web page again and again?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to add a `<p>` element 10 times in the `<body>`.. This is my code

```
body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")
text = document.createElement("p")
text.innerText = "I am batman"

let batman = 10;
for (i=0; i<batman; i++){
    body[0].appendChild(text)
}
```

But the result is that I get only 1 `<p>` on the web page.. But when I create the element inside the for loop it works properly..

Why is this happening? Why was I not able to add same element to the page over and over again.

Comment: _"Why was I not able to add **same** element..."_ - Because there's only one element. `.appendChild()` inserts an element as a new child and does not clone it.

Comment: Also there is this: [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)

Comment: [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild): `Node.appendChild() -
The appendChild() method of the Node interface adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node. If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position.`

Comment: If you read the documentation for `appendChild` on MDN it says so in the second sentence. EDIT: oh, someone just commented that, haha. But yeah, people generally expect you to have done as much research as possible before asking a question here.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a new element within your loop each time it iterates because `.appendChild()` will only do exactly that, append the designated element as a child of the element it's called on. It doesn't create new elements, so using it with an existing element will just move it.

```js
let batman = 10;
for (i=0; i<batman; i++){
  // Each time you loop, create a new element
  let p = document.createElement("p");
  p.textContent = "I am sure";
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating 1 element and try to append that 10 times. Every iteration overwrites the previous. Either create a new `HTMLParagraphElement` every iteration, or use [`Node.cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).
Here's a snippet using the latter.

```js
// create a HTMLParagraphElement (in memory)
const p = Object.assign(document.createElement(`p`), {textContent: `I am batman`});

// append it 10 times using Node.cloneNode 
// (deep, so textContent is cloned too)
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
  document.body.appendChild(p.cloneNode(true));
}
```

Comment: Had never seen that trick to create an element and set its properties in one shot